# SQL Server Cursor Reference (Syntax, etc)

Tags: sql-server, reference, cursors

I don't use SQL Server Cursors often but when I do, I always have to look up the syntax and options.

So I wanted to ask, what is the best SQL Server Cursor reference on the web?.

I'm looking for a reference that explains all of the (major?) options (I.E. FAST_FORWARD) and also shows quick snippets of how to use it.  (I.E. How to implement looping though a cursor and with a good practice for checking the @@FETCH_STATUS variable.)

Best Regards,
Frank

**Quick Update:** I'm looking for a balance of quick-reference but detailed enough to see my options. As an example. MSDN is a great reference guide but it has too much detail. **The reference, ideally, should be concise.**

**Further update:** I'm still looking for sources. If someone posts a good source that fits my criteria of *concise*, I will accept that answer...

Comment: As an aside question/consideration, are you certain a cursor is the best design choice for your problem?

Comment: I'm not trying to 'solve' anything with this question. This is just something that came to mind as a good possible reference to have on Stack Overflow. I've not seen a question like it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start out with the MSDN help page for cursors...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx

Comment: Gets too technical; but it is a solid detailed reference guide.

Answer (score 2):

How to Perform SQL Server Row-by-Row Operations Without Cursors:
    http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/per/operations_no_cursors_p1.aspx

SQL Server Cursor Examples (with Cursor Alternatives):
    http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1599

Answer (score 1):

I always use the built in "Transact-SQL Reference" help within management studio. I find the examples on everything there to be more than enough for what I need.