# T-SQL select process variable

Tags: t-sql, variables, select, process

In SQL Server 2008 I have a Table- Fruits

```
Items   Orders
Bananas 6
Bananas 2
Bananas 1
Mangos  4
Mangos  3
Apples  7
Apples  1
Apples  3
Apples  3
```

Using variables, how I can get below output. I am requesting variables because I would like perform several mathematical operations not described in this example.

```
Items   Number of Orders    Total Order Quantity    Average Order Quantity
Bananas 3   9   3
Mangos  2   7   3.5
Apples  4   14  3.5
```

'Total Order Quantity' shows sum of all orders for given item
'Average Order Quantity' = 'Total Order Quantity'/'Number of Orders'

Many thanks.

```
Create table Fruits (Items varchar(10), Orders int)

insert into Fruits values ('Bananas',6)
insert into Fruits values ('Bananas',2)
insert into Fruits values ('Bananas',1)
insert into Fruits values ('Mangos',4)
insert into Fruits values ('Mangos',3)
insert into Fruits values ('Apples',7)
insert into Fruits values ('Apples',1)
insert into Fruits values ('Apples',3)
insert into Fruits values ('Apples',3)
```

Comment: Can you describe the mathematical operations? Chances are it can be done in a set based way. Using variables will limit you to a fixed maximum number of fruits unless you are planning on processing in a RBAR manner.

Comment: Thanks Gordon Bell. In real scenarios that I have, I would like to perform add, subtractions on "Number of Orders" and "Total Order Quantity" and show it as column

Comment: Is it possible to solve this without cursor? The table I am dealing with has millions of records and is very heavy.

Comment: OP said `I would like to perform add, subtractions on "Number of Orders" and "Total Order Quantity" and show it as column` that sounds totally reasonable for a set based approach.

Comment: You mean you just want to do calculations that involve each row individually or are you talking about running totals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, really should steer clear of cursors when possible.  Something like this approach would probably be best, storing the results of the query in a temporary table, and then running update statements to get your calculations:

```
 declare @Table table
 (
  @Item varchar(10)
  @OrderCount int
  @QuantityTotal int
  @AvgQuantity numeric(9, 2)
  @Calc1 numeric(9, 2)
  @Calc2 numeric(9, 2)
 )

 insert into @Table (@Item, @OrderCount, @QuantityTotal, @AvgQuantity)
 select Items, count(Orders) as NumberOfOrders, sum(Orders) as TotalOrderQuantity, avg(Orders + 0.0) as AverageOrderQuantity
 from Fruits
 group by Items
 order by 1

 update @Table set @Calc1 = @OrderCount / @AvgQuantity,
 @Calc2 = ...

 select * from @Table
```

or if you can get all your calculations in a single row or joins with another table, you can do it in a single statement, like:

```
select *, (OrderCount / AvgQuantity) as Calc1, (... as Calc2)
from
(
 select Items, count(Orders) as OrderCount, sum(Orders) as TotalQuantity, avg(Orders + 0.0) as AvgQuantity
 from Fruits
 group by Items
) t
```

Comment: this starts to become bad when there are many rows. but the OP isn't giving any details.  Remember you can loop without using a cursor.  I have modified nasty slow legacy code containing layers of nested cursors with simple select loops (like found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935336/sql-server-cursor-reference-syntax-etc/935367#935367) and seen major performance boosts.

Answer (score 2):

```
select Items, count(Orders) as NumberOfOrders, sum(Orders) as TotalOrderQuantity, avg(Orders + 0.0) as AverageOrderQuantity
from Fruits
group by Items
```

Comment: beat me to the punch.  +1 sir.

Comment: Completely ignores the requirement to use variables though!

Comment: @Martin, good job! ;-( you comment forced Gordon to use cursors, I hope you are proud of yourself for that!

Comment: +1, good set based answer! the OP said `am requesting variables because I would like perform several mathematical operations not described in this example`, you can do math in a SELECT. Your question should include this "math" so the people here can help you make it set based.

Comment: @KM - Agreed, Given the OP's clarification it is clear that neither cursors or variables are required here (as long as they aren't wanting a running total)

Comment: Like the last column 'Average Order Quantity ' = 'Number of Orders' / 'Total Order Quantity'

Comment: Well just use `count(Orders) / sum(Orders)` for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare csrCursor cursor for
    select Items, count(Orders) as NumberOfOrders, sum(Orders) as TotalOrderQuantity, avg(Orders + 0.0) as AverageOrderQuantity
    from Fruits
    group by Items
    order by 1

declare @Item varchar(10)
declare @OrderCount int
declare @QuantityTotal int
declare @AvgQuantity numeric(9, 2)

open csrCursor

fetch next from csrCursor into @Item, @OrderCount, @QuantityTotal, @AvgQuantity
while (@@fetch_status = 0)
    -- Do stuff with variables @Item, @OrderCount, @QuantityTotal, @AvgQuantity
    -- Insert results in Temp Table

    fetch next from csrCursor into @Item, @OrderCount, @QuantityTotal, @AvgQuantity
end

close csrCursor
deallocate csrCursor
```

Comment: you should add a note in this answer that a set based solution (like your other answer) is way better than this cursor!